# Python client won't reconnect to server

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7, reconnect

I'm sorry for my English, but I've some problems with my software and I need some help. But first of all, some code!

Client side:

```
if connessione.connect(host, port) == True:
    connect = True
    print 'connection granted'
else:
    connect = False
    print 'connection refused'

while 1:
   do_some_stuff_with_socket

   if connect == False:
       if connessione.connect(host, port) == True:
           connect = True
```

Server side:(*found on the internet*)

```
import socket
port = 4000
host = '127.0.0.1'
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind((host, port))
server_socket.listen(5)
print "Type 'Q' or 'q' to QUIT"
print "Server Waiting for client on port ", port
while 1:
    client_socket, address = server_socket.accept()
    print "Connection from ", address
    while 1:
        server_data = raw_input("--> server: ")
        if server_data.lower() == 'q':
            client_socket.send(server_data)
            client_socket.close()
            break
        else:
            client_socket.send(server_data)
        client_data = client_socket.recv(1024)
        if client_data.lower() == 'q':
            print "Quit from client"
            client_socket.close()
            break
        else:
            print "<-- client: ", client_data
    break
```

If I reboot/disconnect the server, the client does not reconnect. I used the `.terminate()` and `.close()` methods to close the socket.

Comment: is there an error thrown when you disconnect?

Comment: why do you have "break" after the print "<-- client: ", client_data?  putting that there will force the outter while 1 to not be rerun. The client_socket, address = server_socket.accept() will not be called again.

Comment: @IT Ninja: No.. No error is thrown... :(

Comment: @DevPlayer: i'll try to remove it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have solved my problem by calling `.__init__()` method before the `.connect(host, port)`

It is not elegant, but it works.

Thanks to all